# HTTP to HTTPS issues

Tags: http, https

I have a question, I am a bit confused, I don't really understand why this is happening.

I have a website which works well over http. When I force redirect to https something happens. Even if I replace all my urls in my code, only GET request will work. Anybody has any idea why is this happening?
I also have admin part of the website. it works to login into the admin but it doesn't work to make any requests on it. I am trying to post or delete but I receive a 401 err, even if I am logged in and set the token right...

So bottom line is:
On Https, the website works, it shows all the resources from the db, I can login in the Admin but I can not post or delete.
On Http everything works.

I am in a huge need of advice or ideas.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you cannot serve mixed content, that's my first suggestion is to call all your scripts/dependencies without the prefix; ie: script src="https://blahblah" to "script src="//blahblah"; you're going to make sure you are sticking consistently to one serving source; so that's the first thing I'd check (also look at console logs, they often give hints as to what failed);

Secondly I am unsure of the response or how the server handles traffic from non https, possibly there's a rule in htaccess or some form of redirection trying to force the call via https so http fails? these are all steps in debugging right you need to troubleshoot and play process of eliminations; first though I'd make sure we are serving everything from // or https; when on http I would look at console logs for clues but even more so I would force a redirect to use https exclusively (as most sites do now)

Check for mixed content issues first though, this is something that can have a multitude of solutions based on the many variations of what could be causing this issue.